# Postgres logical_decoding_work_mem setting in GCP

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

Described problem related to GCP Google Cloud Project

Newest version of Postgres 13 and 14 introduced *logical_decoding_work_mem* parameter to manage replication slot data consumption.
GCP Postgres does not allow to change this attribute through database flag.
There is no such flag on database console,
also

```
gcloud sql instance patch
```

command returns following message

```
The following message will be used for the patch API method.
{"name": "harmonicdb-prod", "project": "innate-empire-283902", "settings": {"databaseFlags": [{"name": "logical_decoding_work_mem", "value": "1024MB"}]}}
WARNING: This patch modifies database flag values, which may require your instance to be restarted. Check the list of supported flags - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags - to see if your instance will be
restarted when this patch is submitted.
```

direct SQL command does not work on GCP Ppostgres SQL due to lack of permissions on GCP SQL

```
 ALTER SYSTEM SET logical_decoding_work_mem = '1024MB'
```

returns following error

```
ERROR:  must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command
the user created on consoile and should have maximum allowed permissions
```

Is it possible to change this parameter in GCP postgres ?